# Sonata admin can't get translation to work with sortable

Tags: php, symfony, translation, sonata-admin

I'm trying to configure translations using Gedmo, but Sortable behaviour I've enabled earlier seems to be getting in a way:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   class 'Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\AbstractTranslatable' was not
>   found in the chain configured namespaces Gedmo\Translatable\Entity,
>   Gedmo\Translator\Entity, Gedmo\Loggable\Entity, Gedmo\Tree\Entity,
>   AppBundle\Entity, Vich\UploaderBundle\Entity,
>   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity,
>   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity, Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity,
>   Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity, Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity,
>   Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity,
>   Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity,
>   FOS\UserBundle\Model").

The template throwing this exception is the one configured for handling of sortable buttons:

```
/Pix/SortableBehaviorBundle/Resources/views/Default/_sort.html.twig (line 3)
```

It fails on line 3 where it's attempting on setting last_position(object)

```
{% if admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and admin.hasRoute('edit') %}
    {% set current_position = currentObjectPosition(object) %}
    {% set last_position    = lastPosition(object) %}
    {% set enable_top_bottom_buttons = field_description.options.actions.move.enable_top_bottom_buttons ?? true %}
    {% if enable_top_bottom_buttons and current_position < last_position %}
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('move', object, {'position': 'bottom'}) }}" title="{{ 'move_to_bottom'|trans }}">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
```

I'm following this translation tutorial:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/translation/master/doc/reference/orm.html

Doctrine ORM Mappings:

```
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    entity_managers:
      default:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
          gedmo_translatable:
            type: annotation
            prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
            alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
            is_bundle: false
          gedmo_translator:
            type: annotation
            prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
            alias: GedmoTranslator # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
            is_bundle: false
          gedmo_loggable:
           type: annotation
           prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
           dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
           alias: GedmoLoggable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
           is_bundle: false
          gedmo_tree:
            type: annotation
            prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
            alias: GedmoTree # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
            is_bundle: false
```

Dump of **doctrine:mapping:info**

```
 Found 36 mapped entities:

 [OK]   Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation
 [OK]   Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation
 [OK]   Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonalTranslation
 [OK]   Gedmo\Translator\Entity\Translation
 [OK]   Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractLogEntry
 [OK]   Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry
 [OK]   Gedmo\Tree\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractClosure
 [OK]   AppBundle\Entity\TeamBio
 [OK]   AppBundle\Entity\User
 [OK]   AppBundle\Entity\NewsItemSource
 [OK]   AppBundle\Entity\NewsItem
 [OK]   AppBundle\Entity\NewsItemTranslation
 [OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseMedia
 [OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseGallery
 [OK]   Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseGalleryHasMedia
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 [OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser
 [OK]   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
 [OK]   Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\BaseComment
 [OK]   Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\BasePost
 [OK]   Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\BaseTag
 [OK]   Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\BaseCollection
 [OK]   Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\BaseCategory
 [OK]   Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\BaseContext
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Comment
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Post
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Collection
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Tag
 [OK]   Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context
 [OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
 [OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have loaded the SonataTranslationBundle in your `AppKernel.php` (symfony 2/3) or in your `bundles.php` (symfony 4).

Verify that you have enabled the gedmo extension in your symfony config:

```
sonata_translation:
    gedmo:
        enabled: true
```

Comment: yeah they are enabled, I can get translation to work and I can get sortable to work, but not together

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sonata translation s **doctrine entity mapping** for directory "sonata-project/translation-bundle/src/Model" is missing.
Try adding it explicitly:

```
mappings:
    MyAdditionalSonataMapping:
              mapping: true
              type: annotation
              dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/sonata-project/translation-bundle/src/Model"
              alias: 'Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model'
              prefix: 'Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model'
              is_bundle: false
```